# Cannot locate find function called in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, function, object, sys

I am quite new to SQL Server. I have an issue where we have a stored procedure called `sys.sp_MSallocate_new_identity_range` (see part of logic below). It makes reference to two functions neither of which I can locate.

```
if (**sys.fn_MSmerge_isrepublisher**(@artid)=0)
    begin
        declare @publisher_max_used numeric(38,0)
        declare @pubid uniqueidentifier
        declare @pub_ranges_needed tinyint
        declare @pub_refresh_constraint bit

        select @pubid = subid, @publisher_max_used = max_used from dbo.MSmerge_identity_range 
            where artid = @artid and is_pub_range = 1 and (**sys.fn_MSmerge_islocalpubid**(subid)=1)
        if @pubid is NULL
        begin
            raiserror(20663, 16, -1)
            return 1
        end
```

Running the stored prcoedure with appropriate parameters - returns a result :

```
declare @p4 smallint
set @p4=2
declare @p5 numeric(38,0)
set @p5=31001
declare @p6 numeric(38,0)
set @p6=32001
declare @p7 numeric(38,0)
set @p7=32001
declare @p8 numeric(38,0)
set @p8=33001
exec sys.sp_MSallocate_new_identity_range 'B551D87F-5457-2102-9E6A-DD4EB44B1DD1','4EB5E2D0-3FC1-4D77-B894-5D57C433D0B2',2,@p4 output,@p5 output,@p6 output,@p7 output,@p8 output,N'dev_02',N'PPC04 - 21a535007fd8',N'My Documents\Assets\assets.sdf'
select @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8
```

i.e This works and returns a result. All Good - but I cannot locate the functions embedded within the stored procedure i.e. `sys.fn_MSmerge_isrepublisher` or `sys.fn_MSmerge_islocalpubid`.

I have looked in `sys.objects` and `sys.all_objects where name like '%fn_MSmerge%'`.

I have managed to trace the SQL and the trace gives an ObjectID and I can see the statement executing. The trace tells me it is a function - 
20038 - FN - and gives me an objectid of 563464549 - but cannot find by looking in sys.objects for the database

Any help/advice gladly accepted.

Comment: What is your actual issue? The procedure is an undocumented, internal system procedure that you are not expected to call yourself. If you describe the actual problem you are experiencing then someone may be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

These object definitions do seem to be hidden. If you connect via the DAC and run

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.fn_MSmerge_islocalpubid'))  AS
       [processing-instruction(x)],
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sys.fn_MSmerge_isrepublisher')) AS
       [processing-instruction(y)]
FOR XML PATH('')
```

you can see them though. The definitions for my version of SQL Server are as below

```
create function sys.fn_MSmerge_islocalpubid (@pubid uniqueidentifier)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @publisher_db sysname
    declare @publisher sysname

    select @publisher_db = publisher_db, @publisher = publisher 
    from dbo.sysmergepublications 
    where pubid = @pubid
    if @publisher_db is NULL or @publisher is NULL
        return 0

    if @publisher_db = db_name() and UPPER(@publisher) = UPPER(publishingservername())
        return 1

    return 0
end


create function sys.fn_MSmerge_isrepublisher (@artid uniqueidentifier)
returns bit
as
begin
    if exists (select pubid from dbo.sysmergearticles where artid = @artid and (sys.fn_MSmerge_islocalpubid(pubid) = 0))
        return 1

    return 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - be able to view the code and using profiler helped us fix our data problem. We were using 2005 and had no debugger - so it was a great help being able to see what the stored procs and functions were actually doing. Cheers